# Should I use DSPACK to record audio (only) from Direct3D devices with Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, audio, direct3d, audio-recording, dspack

I'm trying to save time on a project I'm beginning that will record audio from the connected audio input devices on a Windows XP or Windows 7 PC.  In the past I have used the DSPACK components for Delphi 6 Pro to do video capture on a Windows PC, but I am wondering if it is the best solution for doing a project that only needs to record audio, not video.  Is DSPACK still the way to go or is their a faster/easier solution to recording audio via Direct3D from the PC's connected audio input devices?  Sample rate conversion and other similar features in a suggested solution would be desirable too.  Links to tutorials, etc. are also appreciated.

Comment: IMHO DSPack will save you a lot of time if you have already used it

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with DSPack and using DirectShow filters then it is a good choice for the job. [DSP-Worx](http://www.dsp-worx.de) have an audio filter (DCDSPFilter) that provides a range of effects and they also have DirectShow Interface (LameDShowIntf) to the Lame encoder.

You may also want to consider using [GMFBridge](http://www.progdigy.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2325&sid=2aa56eedb63126952fba86a69b075291) to reduce latencies to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html

I think you can find this components real usefull for your work...